# My loop continuously outputs without stopping

Tags: python

I am trying to make this code break when the user enters "X" and allow it to continue when the user presses enter.
With what I have here, it stop and waits for enter input to output the next name I want it to output but doesn't break when I input X.

```py
def Main():
     userSent = input("Enter X to quit ").upper()`
     while True:
         if userSent == "X":`
             break         
         else:
             print(GenName())
             input()
```

I tried getting rid of the input to fix the problem but then it just continuously went on nonstop. I expected it to break on X or else print GenName() and stop to wait for input.

Comment: It looks like you know how to get user input in Python... So not really sure what you need help with... Consider to review the code before posting and explain it to your favorite rubber duck so you can find typos like missing `userSent = ...` yourself.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "but doesn't break when I input X" When `X` is input, why should that cause the loop to break? Hint: will the value of `userSent` change? Why or why not? Should that matter? Why? For future reference, please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you only define userSent once, right before the loop starts. That means that if the first thing you enter *isnt* a capital X, then the program will never end. Try doing this:

```
def Main():
     while True:
         userSent = input("Enter X to quit ").upper()
         if userSent == "X":
            break  
         else:
             print(GenName())
```

Answer (score 1):

Within your loop, `userSent` is never updated. If the loop enters, it will never exit.

I suspect your last line is meant to be something like `userSent = input()`.

Answer (score 0):

You assign userSent value but you never updated it inside the while loop. You can use either of these versions:

```
def Main():
    userSent = input("Enter X to quit ").upper()
    while userSent != "X":
        print(GenName())
        userSent = input().upper()
```

---

```
def Main():
    userSent = input("Enter X to quit ")
    while userSent != "X" and userSent != "x":
        print(GenName())
        userSent = input()
```